# Deploy application resource files with WSP

Tags: sharepoint-2007, wspbuilder

I am trying to use Sharepoint solution installer to package and deploy my wsp file. My question is how do I deploy the images associated with my webpart? Do I use setup.exe.config (part of Sharepoint solution installer) [http://www.codeplex.com/sharepointinstaller] or do I do this within my WSP template project itself then use the WSP built from that?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can do this within a WSP project template by creating the right folder structure, when the WSP is built it will add the required entries into the manifest.xml generated within the WSP file.

See the link

http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2009/07/24/adding-sharepoint-class-resources-to-your-feature-using-wspbuilder.aspx